# C programming arrays big level

Tags: c, arrays

So im getting a file with strings, i want to tokenize each string whenever i come to a whitespace/newline. i am able to get the tokens seperated into delimiter strings, but im not able to copy them into an array.

```
int lexer(FILE* file){

char line[50];
char* delim;
int i = 0;
int* intptr = &i;


while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),file)){
    printf("%s\n", line);

    if(is_empty(line) == 1)
        continue;

    delim = strtok(line," ");

    if(delim == NULL)
        printf("%s\n", "ERROR");

    while(delim != NULL){

        if(delim[0] == '\n'){
        //rintf("%s\n", "olala");
            break;
        }
        tokenArray[*intptr] = delim;
        printf("Token IN array: %s\n", tokenArray[*intptr]);
        *intptr = *intptr + 1;
        delim = strtok(NULL, " ");

    }
```

if i run this i get the output :

Token IN array: 012

Token IN array: 23ddd

Token IN array: vs32

Token IN array: ,344

Token IN array: 0sdf

which is correct according to my textfile, but when i try to reprint the array at a later time in the same function and out

```
    *intptr = *intptr + 1;
        delim = strtok(NULL, " ");

    }



}
printf("%s\n", tokenArray[3]);
fclose(file);
return 0;
```

i dont get an output, i tried writing all the contents of the array to a txt file, i got gibberish. i dont know what to do plz help

Answer (score 1):

First, your pointer on i is useless. Why not using i directly?
I'll assume that from now on.

Then, the real problem: you have to allocate and copy the strings that strtok returns each time because strtok does not allocate the tokens for you, it justs points to the last one. The references are all the same, so you get last empty token

Something like this would help:

```
tokenArray[*intptr] = strdup(delim);
```

(instead of `tokenArray[*intptr] = delim;`) note that I have replaced the index by i. Just to `i++` afterwards.

BTW I wouldn't recommend using `strtok` for other purposes that quick hacks. This function has a memory, so if you call several functions using it in different parts of your program, it can conflict (I made that mistake a long time ago). Check manual for `strtok_r` in that case (r for reentrant)

Answer (score 0):

```
tokenArray[*intptr] = delim;
```

In this line, `delim` is a pointer to a char array of which the content is ever changing in the for loop. So in your case, the content which `delim` point to should be copied as content of `tokenArray[*intptr]`, that is:

```
tokenArray[*intptr] = strdup(delim);
```